# How do I print the line number with each matched line?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to extract some lines from a file and output the line number in front of each extracted line.

For example, with the following input in a file named `file`

```
This is line1
This is line2
This is test1
This is test2
This is linex
```

After I execute the perl command

```
perl -ne 'if (/test/) {print "$_"}' file
```

I obtain this:

```
This is test1
This is test2
```

But I want to insert the line number at the beginning of the line.

```
line3: This is test1
line4: This is test2
```

How can I insert the line number?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The variable that keep the line number is `$.`, so use it interpolated in the double quotes of the `print` function:

```
perl -ne 'if (/test/) {print "line$.: $_"}' file
```

It yields:

```
line3: This is test1
line4: This is test2
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually I think it is easier with using grep:

```
grep -n test file
```